# Why is this regex wrong in the STL world?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, stl, c++17

Why is this regex wrong in the STL world?

```
(?<=^EXTINF:)*(\d+\.\d+)
```

The "?<=" part throws an exception. Why???

Update:

> const char * const pm3u = 
> {
>  "#EXTM3U\n" "#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n"
>   "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:153741\n" 
> "#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO\n"
>   "#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11\n" 
> "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-29.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:9.984000,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-39.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-49.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-59.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-09.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:9.984000,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-19.ts\n"
>  };
>
> int main()
>  {
>       std::regex regExpression( "(#EXTINF:)(\\d+.\\d+)*" );
>       std::smatch regExMatch;
>       const std::string str( pm3u );
>       bool b = std::regex_match( str.begin(), str.end(), regExMatch, regExpression );
>   return 0;
>   }

Comment: Well, what does the actual error tell you? And what does your actual line of code look like?

Comment: You should use `^EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+)` and access group 1. ECMAScript engine does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: @Wiktor, true, that removes the error, but it's not functional.... argh... what a crap is this STL regex....

Comment: What do you mean? If you need to match start of a line, replace  `^` with `(?:^|\n)`. Please post a snippet with your code that does not work.

Comment: Note you may have omitted `#` before `EXTINF` if you have the input as in your previous question.

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/yGzBjw

Comment: @Wiktor, I'm on MS C++ compiler.

Comment: std::regex (Visual C++ 2017) does not support lookbehind

Comment: @Wiktor, wanna post it as the answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure it will work the way you need. I will post with explanations now.

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex can be fixed if

- You convert the lookbehind to a consuming pattern
- If you replace `^` with `(?:^|\n)` to match start of lines, not just the start of the string
- If you use an `std::sregex_iterator` to match multiple matches instead of `std::regex_match` that only matches the whole string (i.e. the pattern must match the whole string)
- If you add the `#` before `EXTINF` since your expected matches start with `#EXTINF`.

Use

```
const std::regex rx(R"((?:^|\n)#EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+),[\r\n]+(.*))");
   std::string test = "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:153741\n#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-29.ts\n#EXTINF:9.984000,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-39.ts\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-49.ts\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-59.ts\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-09.ts\n#EXTINF:9.984000,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-19.ts";
   for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), rx);
                         i != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++i)
   {
    std::smatch m = *i;
    std::cout << "Part 1:"  << m[1].str() << "\nPart 2:"  << m[2].str() << std::endl;
   }
```

The regex is

```
(?:^|\n)#EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+),[\r\n]+(.*)
```

See [this regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/b6zvf5/1).